# So, "My eyes are irritated" or "My eyes are irritating"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, adjectives

"**My eyes are irritated**" or "**My eyes are irritating**"?

[On Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=irritated%20eyes%2C%20irritating%20eyes&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cirritated%20eyes%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cirritating%20eyes%3B%2Cc0) much more people say "**irritated eyes**" than "**irritating eyes**".

Googling "My eyes are irritated" returns 24k results ([Link](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=%22My%20eyes%20are%20irritated%22&oq=%22My%20eyes%20are%20irritated%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6285j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8))

Googling "My eyes are irritating" returns 40k results ([Link](https://www.google.com.vn/search?q=%22My%20eyes%20are%20irritated%22&oq=%22My%20eyes%20are%20irritated%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.6285j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22My%20eyes%20are%20irritating%22))

I would say "My eyes are irritated" does not make sense because **only human can feel**, **human's eyes can not feel**. (we say "**I am very excited because the film is very exciting**")

"**My eyes are irritating**" sounds better because it is making the man irritated.

So, "**My eyes are irritated**" or "**My eyes are irritating**"?

Comment: Look up *irritated* in a dictionary. Also, please add the meaning you want to convey.

Comment: A perfect example of why ngrams are often meaningless. Is this interesting? Are you interested in this? If your eyes are irritating, you are bothering someone.

Answer (score 3):

> my eyes are irritated
>   *my eyes are uncomfortable and hurt*
>
> my eyes are irritating
>   *my eyes are annoying someone*

Usually your eyes, themselves, will not irritate someone, however *staring* will.

> My eyes are irritated.
>   My eyes are irritating me.

would basically have the same meaning that your eyes are bothering you, the first by implication, the second by direct mention

Answer (score 1):

The eyes have nerve endings that relay information to the brain. In this way, our eyes do feel, and "my eyes are irritated" is quite logical.

▶ Dust particles in the air irritate my eyes.
My eyes are irritated.

My friend's cat cuddles up to me only when I'm wearing sunglasses. My eyes must be irritating.

Answer (score 1):

In AmE, "irritate" is  most often transitive, although a few speakers use **are irritating** to mean "are getting irritated" or "are having irritation".

> {This chemical} <sup>subj</sup> **irritates** <sup>v.t.</sup> {the eyes}  <sup>object</sup>.

The noun for the resulting state is **irritation**.

The predicate adjective formed from the past participle is **irritated**.

The adjective **irritating**  and the progressive form of the verb **irritating** mean "causing irritation".

> My eyes are **irritated** because I was working with that chemical, which is **irritating** to the eyes.
>   -- What is the name of the chemical **irritating** your eyes?

The relatively rare intransitive use where it means "to become irritated" or "to have irritation":

> My eyes are irritating a lot lately. They are always itchy and tearing.

Normally, we'd see the reflexive "My eyes are irritating **me**..." which would be analogous to "My knee has been paining me lately".

Comment: A different take: "Irritating" can mean causing someone to become angry or upset.  "My eyes are irritating" could mean that you are bothered by some characteristic of your eyes, say relating to their appearance.

Comment: Yes, but the eyes example (rather than a stuck zipper example, say) suggests that the OP's question is about the physical malady, not the "ticked off, irked" meaning.